# Ubuntu 14.04.1 multiple SSL certificates error

Tags: apache, ssl, webserver, virtualhost, vhosts

I have setup 2 websites on my Ubuntu web server and am having some trouble with getting two SSL certificates to work correctly. I did get one working on it's own at first, however, now I can't restart Apache successfully.

**Error when trying to restart Apache**

```
 * Restarting web server apache2
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website1.conf:
ServerName takes one argument, The hostname and port of the server
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

**Output of /etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**Output of website1.conf (first vhost file from /etc/apache2/sites-available)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@localhost
    ServerName www.website1.com website1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website1.com/public
    Redirect permanent /secure https://website1.com
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin support@localhost
    ServerName website1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website1.com/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/website1.com/private/website1.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/website1.com/private/website1_private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/html/website1.com/private/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

**Output of website1.conf (second vhost file from /etc/apache2/sites-available)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@localhost
    ServerAlias www.website2.com website2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website2.com/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin support@localhost
    ServerName website2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website2.com/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/website2.com/private/website2.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/website2.com/private/website2_private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/html/website2.com/private/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help or verification of my config would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.